# How to get an item

Tags: java, jsp, el

JSP tag code is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="items" required="true" %>
${items[0]}
```

JSP code is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<t:input items="${form.items}"></t:input>
```

Maybe I forgot type of the attribute or something else? Why is the way to access values different in JSP and JSP tag?

Comment: Are you getting some error or it's not working as you expect? What actually happens when you run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default type of attributes is `java.lang.String`. If you expect something else, specify the expected type:

```
<%@ attribute name="items" required="java.util.Collection" %>
```

or

```
<%@ attribute name="items" required="java.lang.Object" %>
```

for example.